# Go Templates - Check whether a key exists in json list

Tags: go, kubernetes, coreos, go-templates, confd

I am using [confd](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd) for a dynamic nginx service reconfiguration and having a bit of a struggle with the Go Templates. I have a json object named `$data` and `$data.subsets` may contain a key named 'addresses' -- I want to only execute the template inside the loop if that condition is met.

I've tried various things like the `$data.subsets[0].addresses` you see below which is completely wrong. I am not really sure how this can be done correctly.

This is a piece of my nginx template that I only want to render if there is at least 1 upstream service, not if there are none/unavailable.

Following the template is the json objects for `$data` on success any failure.

Thank you in advance for the help, it's greatly appreciated!

```
{{ range $ns := getvs "/registry/services/endpoints/*/app" }}
{{ $data := json $ns }}
    {{ if $data.subsets[0].addresses }}
upstream {{ $data.metadata.namespace }}_{{ $data.metadata.name }}_pool {
        {{ range $subset := $data.subsets }}{{ range $ref := $subset.addresses }}{{ range $portConfig := $subset.ports }}
 server {{ $ref.ip }}:{{ $portConfig.port }};
        {{ end }}{{ end }}{{ end }}
}
    {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

Example of `$data` when there are no Pods scheduled:

```
{  
   "kind":"Endpoints",
   "apiVersion":"v1",
   "metadata":{  
      "name":"app",
      "namespace":"ns1",
      "selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/ns1/endpoints/app",
      "labels":{  
         "app":"app"
      }
   },
   "subsets":[]
}
```

Example of `$data` when there are pods running but not healthy:

```
{  
   "kind":"Endpoints",
   "apiVersion":"v1",
   "metadata":{  
      "name":"app",
      "namespace":"ns1",
      "labels":{  
         "app":"app"
      }
   },
   "subsets":[  
      {  
         "notReadyAddresses":[  
            {  
               "ip":"10.254.60.5",
               "targetRef":{  
                  "kind":"Pod",
                  "namespace":"ns1",
                  "name":"app-421757659-83rfg",
               }
            }
         ],
         "ports":[  
            {  
               "name":"ns1-app-8080",
               "port":8080,
               "protocol":"TCP"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Example of `$data` when there are pods running and available. This is the only condition I wish to meet for the iteration of the template to render.

```
{  
   "kind":"Endpoints",
   "apiVersion":"v1",
   "metadata":{  
      "name":"app",
      "namespace":"ns1",
      "selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/ns1/endpoints/app",
      "labels":{  
         "app":"app"
      }
   },
   "subsets":[  
      {  
         "addresses":[  
            {  
               "ip":"10.254.18.11",
               "targetRef":{  
                  "kind":"Pod",
                  "namespace":"ns1",
                  "name":"app-3869480132-kfthi"
               }
            },
            {  
               "ip":"10.254.18.9",
               "targetRef":{  
                  "kind":"Pod",
                  "namespace":"ns1",
                  "name":"app-3869480132-9bufk"
               }
            }
         ],
         "ports":[  
            {  
               "name":"ns1-app-8080",
               "port":8080,
               "protocol":"TCP"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Why don't you check the condition in normal Go code with normal json handling and then just pass a bool into the template? Accessing the values in your json is pretty straight forward regardless of which variation it is however I'm not really sure how you would do that given the libraries in play in that context. Unless the `$data` object is used heavily elsewhere I don't think it should be passed to the template at all since most of it is irrelevant in that context. In fact you should probably just extract the addresses list and pass that and have none of this logic in your template.

Answer (score 2):

The `$data.subsets[0].addresses` is illegal template expression (contains `[` and `]`). Try the following template definition:

```
{{range $cfg := getvs "/registry/services/endpoints/*/app"}}
{{$data := json $cfg}}
{{range $data.subsets}}{{range $addr := .addresses}}
{{with $ns := $addr.targetRef.namespace}}
upstream {{$ns}}_{{$addr.targetRef.name}}_pool {
    {{range $data.subsets}}{{range $port := .ports}}
        {{/* 
            Split port.name then test if address namespace 
            match the port.name. Test Condition:
            len($portDesc) > 0 && $portDesc[0] == $ns
        */}}
        {{$portDesc := split $port.name "-"}}
        {{if and (gt (len $portDesc) 0) (eq (index $portDesc 0) $ns)}}
  server {{ $addr.ip }}:{{ $port.port }};
        {{end}}
    {{end}}{{ end }}
}
{{end}}
{{end}}{{end}}
```

Generated output(after removing empty lines) for the above three json data should be:

```
upstream ns1_app-3869480132-kfthi_pool {
  server 10.254.18.11:8080;
}
upstream ns1_app-3869480132-9bufk_pool {
  server 10.254.18.9:8080;
}
```

The key is `range` action in `{{range $data.subsets}}{{range $addr := .addresses}}`. Nothing will be written if `len` of pipeline (`subsets` or `addresses`) is zero, i.e. when `subsets` does not contains element or `addresses` is `null` (no subsets element named `addresses`).